# Ranking Sectors Based on "Inclusiveness", greater variance among sectors with less firms

Tags: firm, ranking

I am trying to rank sectors in Serbia based on how "inclusive" they are in their development, i.e. I have some indicators such as "share of profitable firms within sector", "share of exporting firms within tradable sector", etc.

However, Serbian sectors that have less firms overall inevitably end up either always at the higher or lower end of the ranking because their sample size is smaller I end up with larger variance among them...

Anyone know any methods to adapt measure such as those I mentioned above as to minimize the effects of these variances, but still retain some of the originally intended information?

Thank you!

Comment: It's common practice to divide variances by the square of sample size, have you any reason not to do so?